# How to disable the confirmation of history expansions like `!!`

Tags: zsh, command-history

Zsh takes real good care of me, and at times it can get a bit too much. One of the times where I'd rather have it stay out of my business is when it "wants to make sure I want to execute the given command". The functions I am experiencing this with are:

**The commands:**

`sudo !!` -  run previous command prefixed with sudo 

and
`^old^new` - run previous command, but substitute the first occurrence of "old" with "new"

**The problem:**

When I type in one of the two commands listed above and hit `Enter`, instead of running the command instantly, the command expands to what is actually going to be run, and I have to hit `Enter` once again to actually execute it. First world problem, but still.

```
1 $ pwd
2 /home/neil
3 $ sudo !!
4 $ sudo pwd
5 /home/neil
```

I'd like to skip step 4. **This is skipped by default in bash.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's easy... if you know the corresponding option:

```
unsetopt HIST_VERIFY
```

Put this in your `~/.zshrc` and do `source ~/.zshrc` if you want that behavior to be permanent.

Explanation from `man zshoptions`:

> `HIST_VERIFY`              Whenever  the user enters a line with history expansion, don't execute the line directly; instead, perform history expansion and reload the
>                 line into the editing buffer.

Comment: I would, but it appears `upsetopt HIST_VERIFY` doesn't kick in if I put it in `.zshrc` and manually source it. I am sure the config file is the one being loaded too. The command only works for me if I run it in a zsh prompt like any other command.

Comment: And yeah, tried restarting the terminal emulator as well. Odd.

Comment: It's `unsetopt` (just to make sure ;). Do you use oh-my-zsh or something similar?

Comment: I sure do. Does oh-my-zsh break config lines like this when it gets sourced?

Comment: Just tried it out, and it turns out I had to make sure `oh-my-zsh` is sourced before the command is ran. Solved!

Comment: Sorry to say that, but oh-my-zsh is a source of a lot of annoyances. And yes it is setting `HIST_VERIFY` in `lib/history.zsh`. However it should work if you put the `unsetopt` command at the _end_ of `~/.zshrc`, especially _after_ `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Comment: @krystah : Perfect, you figured it out yourself `:)`